# RestFB: No user access token specified

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm struggling with RestFB 2.0.

This is my simple code:

```
        AccessToken accessToken =
            new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_11).obtainAppAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);
    FacebookClient fc = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken(), Version.VERSION_2_11);
    AccessToken extendedAccessToken = fc.obtainExtendedAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);
```

But on line #3 I get this error:

```
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: No user access token specified (code 1, subcode null)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: implement user login then, to get a user token...

Comment: you cannot extend a app access token...